# XML Parsing with C# and XDocument - XmlException: 'file' is expected

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I've got this error:

XmlException: 'chipdb' is expected file:///C:/Users/Mkh/Documents/MMBN3D/Assets/Resources/ChipDatabase.xml Line 12, position 8.

When trying to parse the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<chipdb>
    <chip>
        <name> Cannon1 </name>
        <dmg> 30 </dmg>
        <smallicon> </smallicon>
        <bigicon> </bigicon>
        <type> Straight </type>
        <element> None </element>
        <description> One of the most basic chips. </description>
    </chip>
</chipbd>
```

I only need to find the correct chip, and then use this data to initiate a chip object that will be used elsewhere. To do this I am using XDocument, and had some trouble with it because I never worked with XML. The code I made is the following:

```
    using UnityEngine;

using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections;

public class XMLAttackParser : MonoBehaviour
{
    XDocument doc;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        doc = new XDocument();
        doc = XDocument.Load( "Assets/Resources/ChipDatabase.xml" );
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    bool searchChip ( string name )
    {
        var chips = doc.Descendants( "chip" );

        foreach (var item in chips)
        {
            if( item.Element( "name" ).ToString() == name )
            {
                Debug.Log( "Man" );
                return true;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Your closing tag is `</chipbd>`...

Comment: Oh... -.- I spent a few hours on this... Should I delete this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mistyped `chipdb` for the closing tag at the end of the document: `chipbd`.

Someone had pointed out (but removed his message) that you also have a mistake on: `item.Element( "name" ).ToString()` which should be:

```
item.Element( "name" ).Value
```

or

```
(string)item.Element("name")
```

Indeed, `item.Element( "name" ).ToString()` will return: `<name> cannon1 </name>`